Why does a Mathematica simulation of first hitting times of a stochastic process not match the theoretical result?
Let $ \theta, \sigma, \mu $ be positive real numbers.
We consider the following mean reverting stochastic process $d X_t = \theta \cdot (\mu- X_t) dt + \sigma d B_t $ where $X_0 = x$ . Here $B_t$ is the Brownian motion. The process in question is known as the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. It is mean reverting and its properties are well known.
In particular it is known that, there  exist two linearly independent eigen-functions $F_r(x)$ and $G_r(x)$, to the eigenvalue $r>0$, of the infinitesimal generator ${\mathfrak G}_x:= \theta (\mu-x) d/dx + \sigma^2/2 \cdot d^2/d x^2 $.
Those eigenfunctions that  are both being positive with the first one being strictly increasing and the other one strictly decreasing.
Those eigen-functions read:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_r(x) &=& \int\limits_0^\infty u^{\zeta-1} \cdot e^{A (x-\theta) u- \frac{u^2}{2}} du 
&=&
2^{\frac{\zeta }{2}-1} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{\zeta }{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{\zeta }{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2} A^2 (x-\theta
   )^2\right)+\sqrt{2} A \Gamma \left(\frac{\zeta +1}{2}\right) (x-\theta ) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{\zeta +1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{2} A^2 (x-\theta
   )^2\right)\right) \\
G_r(x) &=& \int\limits_0^\infty u^{\zeta-1} \cdot e^{A (\theta-x) u- \frac{u^2}{2}} du 
&=& 2^{\frac{\zeta }{2}-1} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{\zeta }{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{\zeta }{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2} A^2 (x-\theta
   )^2\right)+\sqrt{2} A \Gamma \left(\frac{\zeta +1}{2}\right) (\theta -x) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{\zeta +1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{2} A^2 (x-\theta
   )^2\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\zeta:=r/\mu$ and $A:=\sqrt{(2\mu)/\sigma^2}$.

Now, according to section 4.6 in K Ito, Henry P McKean Jr, "Diffusion Processes and their Sample Paths", the Laplace transform $E_x \left[ e^{-r \cdot \tau_b} \right] := E \left[ e^{-r \cdot \tau_b} | X_0=x\right]$of the first hitting time $\tau_b:= inf( t>0| X_t >b )$ distribution takes the following form:
\begin{eqnarray}
E_x \left[ e^{-r \cdot \tau_b} \right] 
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{F_r(x)}{F_r(b)} & \mbox{if $x \le b$} \\
\frac{G_r(x)}{G_r(b)} & \mbox{if $x > b$} \\
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
We have chosen to verify the result $(1)$ via a Monte Carlo simulation by using Mathematica.
We took $\mu,r,\sigma, \theta= 5,3,3,1.1 $ and the first value $x= 1/2$ .
Then we simulated $num=1000,5000$ instances of the process in question on a time grid $ t= i \cdot dt $ with $i=0,\cdots, \lfloor t_{max}/dt \rfloor $ with $dt=0.01$ and $t_{max}=10$.
Here the command being used was ItoProcess[] along with RandomFunction[].
For each instance of the process l1 we constructed its running maximum via the command l2= FoldList[Max,l1] and then we determined the first hitting time of the barrier $b$ by finding the (unique) root of the equation Interpolation[l2]==b.
Then we averaged the left hand side of $(1)$ over those random times and finally we plotted the result as a function of the barrier $b$.
The definitions in the code:
(*This is our strictly increasing eigen-function F[x] of the \
infinitesimal operator .*)
F[x_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, \[Theta]_, r_] := 
  With[{\[Zeta] = r/\[Mu], A = Sqrt[(2 \[Mu])/\[Sigma]^2]}, 
   2^(-1 + \[Zeta]/
     2)  (Gamma[\[Zeta]/2]  Hypergeometric1F1[\[Zeta]/2, 1/2, 
        1/2  A^2  (x - \[Theta])^2] + 
      Sqrt[2]  A  (x - \[Theta])  Gamma[(1 + \[Zeta])/
        2]  Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + \[Zeta])/2, 3/2, 
        1/2  A^2  (x - \[Theta])^2])
   ];
(*Problems with simulating the first hitting time distribution in the \
Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.*)
Clear[\[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], x, t, dt]; x0 = 1/2;
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
      t] == \[Theta] (\[Mu] - 
        x[t])  \[DifferentialD]t + (\[Sigma]  x[
         t])  \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, x0}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];

The body of the code being used is given below.
{\[Mu], r, \[Sigma], \[Theta]} = {5, 3, Sqrt[9], 1.1};
num = 5000; dt = 0.01; tmax = 10;
rf = RandomFunction[proc, {0., tmax, dt}, num, 
   Method -> "KloedenPlatenSchurz"];

mLL = {}; bs = Array[# &, 100, {1/2, 5}];
Do[
  b = bs[[which]];
  mll = {};
  Do[
   l1 = rf[[2, 1]][[p, All]];
   l2 = FoldList[Max, l1 - b];
   f = Interpolation[l2];
   tind = t /. FindRoot[f[t] == 0, {t, 1, Floor[tmax/dt] + 1}];
   If[ ! NumberQ[tind] || ! (1 <= tind <= Floor[tmax/dt] + 1),
    {tstar, mExp} = {NaN, NaN},
    tstar = dt*(tind - 1);
    mExp = Exp[-r*tstar];
    ];
   mll = Join[mll, {{tstar, mExp}}];
   , {p, 1, Length[rf[[2, 1]]]}];
  
  mll1 = Select[mll, NumberQ[#[[2]]] &];
  mLL = Join[
    mLL, {{b, Mean[mll1[[All, 2]]], Sqrt@Variance[mll1[[All, 2]]], 
      Length[mll1]/Length[mll]}}];
  PrintTemporary["b=", N@bs[[which]], " done."];
  , {which, 1, Length[bs]}];

The plotting part of the code:
ListPlot[{{#[[1]], Around[#[[2]], #[[3]]]} & /@ 
   mLL, {#, 
     F[x0, \[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], r]/
      F[#, \[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], r]} & /@ bs}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"b", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(x\)]\)[Exp[-r \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Tau]\), \(b\)]\)]]"}, PlotLegends -> {"MC", "theory"}]

The results of that Monte Carlo simulation (blue dots along with blue error bars) were overlain with the theoretical curve as in $(1)$ and are shown below.

Clearly the simulation does not match the theory! For big values of $b$ the simulated first hitting times are systematically too small when compared to the theoretical results. The result does not seem to change when we increase the number of instances num nor does it change upon increase of the time span $t_{max}$.
What is the reason for this?

There was a bug in the simulation code. The second term in the  first argument of the ItoProcess[] routine  should be $\sigma d W_t $ rather than  $\sigma X_t d W_t $ as it is now. Changing this brings the blue curve down a bit but still  it is far from the orange one especially for the biggest $b$.

I have mistakenly swapped the parameters $\mu$ and $\theta$!
In reality it is $\theta$ that is the long term mean and $\mu$ is the rate of convergence towards the long term mean.So both the process and the infinitesimal generator, as given in the body of the question, are incorrect.
The correct versions read as below:
\begin{eqnarray}
d X_t &=& \mu \left( \theta - X_t \right) dt + \sigma d B_t \\
{\mathfrak G}_x &=& \mu \left( \theta - x \right) \frac{d}{d x} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{d^2}{d x^2} 
\end{eqnarray}
With this having fixed we firstly verify that the eigenfunctions have the correct form by using the code below:
In[198]:= (*This is our strictly increasing (decreasing) \
eigen-function F[x] (G[x]) of the infinitesimal operator .*)
Clear[F, G, \[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], x, t, dt];
F[x_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, \[Theta]_, r_] := 
  With[{\[Zeta] = r/\[Mu], A = Sqrt[(2 \[Mu])/\[Sigma]^2]}, 
   2^(-1 + \[Zeta]/
     2)  (Gamma[\[Zeta]/2] Hypergeometric1F1[\[Zeta]/2, 1/2, 
        1/2 A^2 (x - \[Theta])^2] + 
      Sqrt[2] A (x - \[Theta]) Gamma[(1 + \[Zeta])/
        2] Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + \[Zeta])/2, 3/2, 
        1/2 A^2 (x - \[Theta])^2])
   ];
G[x_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, \[Theta]_, r_] := 
  With[{\[Zeta] = r/\[Mu], A = Sqrt[(2 \[Mu])/\[Sigma]^2]}, 
   2^(-1 + \[Zeta]/
     2)  (Gamma[\[Zeta]/2]  Hypergeometric1F1[\[Zeta]/2, 1/2, 
        1/2  A^2  (x - \[Theta])^2] + 
      Sqrt[2]  A  (\[Theta] - x)  Gamma[(1 + \[Zeta])/
        2]  Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + \[Zeta])/2, 3/2, 
        1/2  A^2  (x - \[Theta])^2])
   ];
(\[Mu] (\[Theta] - x) D[#, x] + \[Sigma]^2/2  D[#, {x, 2}] - 
     r #) & /@ {F[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], r], 
   G[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Theta], r]} // FullSimplify

Out[201]= {0, 0}

Now, I have to swap $\mu$ and $\theta$ in the definitions part of the code, in the ItoProcess command to be exact. If I do this and, in addition to that, also fix the volatility term, i.e. replace the $\sigma X_t dW_t $ just by $\sigma dW_t$ then I get the following result(here the top plot was produced by using the numerical solver and the bottom plot by using the closed form solution):

Both results match the theory well and the closed form expression yields better results (as it should be).
